# Solving Riccati equation $y^{\prime}=x^2-y^2$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to draw the solution curve of the Riccati equation $y^{\prime}=x^2-y^2$, and I met some problem:

On the one hand, I tried substitution
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u=x+y
\\ v=x-y
\end{array}\right.
,
$$
which leads to
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dv}
=\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dv}
=\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}
=(x+y)(x-y)
=uv. 
$$
This is separable and the solutions are
$$
u=0\text{ and }\ln\left|\dfrac{u}{C}\right|=\dfrac{1}{2}v^2\Rightarrow y=-x\text{ and }x+y=C\mathrm e^{\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}},
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

[image]

On the other hand, I tried to draw the slope field and the curve in the picture above does not fit the field, since on $y=x$ the slope should be $0$.

I wonder if I've made any mistake. Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Note that $du/dv \ne dy/dx$

Comment: You can use $u=\exp(\int y(x)\,dx)$, $y=\frac{u'}{u}$ to get $u''=x^2u$ and then apply WKB approximations or explore the relation to Airy and Bessel and other special functions.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb How should I calculate $\mathrm du/\mathrm dv$? Is it partial derivative or something?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Yes, $du = dx + dy$ and $dv = dx - dy$, so $\frac{du}{dv} = \frac{dx+dy}{dx-dy} = \frac{1+y'}{1-y'}$. Use the solution by @LutzLehmann to find a proper solution to this DE.

Comment: $\dfrac {du}{dv}=\dfrac {1+uv}{1-uv}$ in fact.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aryadeva Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome @EricMonlye

Comment: I do not see a reason to change variables, in direction of positive $x$ the solution will rapidly approach the stable asymptote $y=x$ for all initial points with $y_0>-x_0$, in the opposing case $y_0<-x_0-1$ or so, the solution will rapidly diverge to $-\infty$ like a first order pole. In negative $x$-direction the situation is the same, but sign-reversed. If you want to stabilize the numerical computation, use $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac1R$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{R}$ where $R=\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}$, so that all solution trajectories exist for all $t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y'=x^2-y^2$$
Why not the usual way to solve Riccati ODEs ?

Let $y=\frac{u'}{u}$
$$y'=\frac{u''}{u}-\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}=x^2-\left(\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2$$
$$u''-x^2u=0$$
This is a second order ODE of Bessel kind. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html From Eqs.(6-7) the solution is :
$$u=c_1x^{1/2}I_{1/4}(x^2/2)+c_2x^{1/2}I_{-1/4}(x^2/2)$$
$I_{\nu}(z)$ denotes the modified Bessel functions of first kind https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Then differentiate wrt $x$ to find $u'(x)$ and $y(x)=u'(x)/u(x)$ .

Note :  in case of $I_{\pm 1/4}$ one can use the Parabolic Cylinder functions. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html

Comment: Hi Jean ! How are you in this terrible time ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi Claude ! I love to hear from you. I am fine.  I wish the same for you. Cheers.